# $\frac{dy}{dx}$ application to derivative

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble understanding how $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is applied to a resulting formula.

For example,

The derivative of $xy$, after the product rule, is going to be $$y+x \frac{dy}{dx}$$

I thought the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ was multiplied by the whole expression $(y+x)$, but in a current problem I'm working on, it is telling me it is only multiplied by the latter value, $x$.

So the answer reads like $y + \left(x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$. Is this correct? Why does the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ apply only to the second term?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please use MathJax for a better reading: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Use the product rule
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(xy(x))
=y\frac{d}{dx}(x)+x\frac{d}{dx}(y(x))
=y+x\frac{dy}{dx}.
$$